# Make an overlapping button

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a flap infront of the buton... any ideas?

```
.button {
    position:absolute;
    top:240px;
    left: 452.5px;
    width:110px;
    height:40px; 
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid #009c93 1px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    background: #009c93;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #222222);
}
```

Comment: You are looking for `<input placeholder="blabla" />` if I understand you

Comment: maybe, but the overlap is a triangle shape, hovering over the textbox, is the possible through placeholders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using this:

```
.button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #D83C3C transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}
```

BTW. Placeholder has nothing to do with this! It's pure CSS.

Comment: Please consider changing your tagline typography, for the sake of humanity.

Comment: @Connor try to add this code to your script and see how can you change it to achieve what you need. Learning should be fun :)

Comment: @Kayo is that written for me?

Comment: could you please tell me how i would adapt it to my site as i tried changing the div names, adding it, adding it to the button, but I don't understand, its not working

Comment: Copy this code to the bottom of you CSS script and tell me when you have done it so I can check it online and see what you need to rewrite

Comment: That's for me an amazing new function using border-style. Im suprised that the triangle appears. Is there any documentation or standard for this? What exactly happens? I would expect just 3 borders at top, right and bottom...

Comment: It was aimed at Connor. Just some jest.

Comment: btw. why not adding this triangle as small positioned background picture to the inputfield? Consider using base64 png.

Comment: ok I have copied the code to my css, what do we need to change?

Comment: @Connor I really don't have time to work on your code...what I can suggest is to inspect elements and styles on their website and try to apply it on your code...

Comment: @abimelex they are using `before` so they can draw and empty element in the button. if you look at their css you can see that the red triangle is basically a white square which is styled ( borders, size and so on...)...this is a great idea to use CSS

Comment: i still don't know whats wrong, i can read and acces my code, but i don;t know what to look for

Comment: besides, was it you who said this? Copy this code to the bottom of you CSS script and tell me when you have done it so I can check it online and see what you need to rewrite

Comment: yes I did @Connor but your CSS needs to be modified a lot, and that's why I don't have time for it...This is the answer that you were looking for...you need to learn how to change your code...copy/paste is not always your only option

Comment: im not asking you to edit my code, im asking how to fit this new code into it, if there is anything that needs to be changed

Comment: take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8q9q2/4/ it seems that the ::before method doesn't works for submit field, that's why I wrapped a div arround it.

Comment: nice @abimelex I really hope that he will use it